# Retrieving audio information of multiple wav files in r

Tags: wav, sound, samplerate

I would like to ask if I could retrieve information, such as sample rate, bit rate, length of file, and stereo/mono layout, from multiple .wav files at a time in R, from a file list for example? Most packages only allow me process single sound files. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

you can do that with the package warbleR. The code below saves a couple of sound files (for the sake of the example) and gives you the info you want in a data frame:

> library(warbleR)
>
> data(list = c("Phae.long1", "Phae.long2"))
>
> writeWave(Phae.long1, file.path(tempdir(), "Phae.long1.wav"))
>
> writeWave(Phae.long2, file.path(tempdir(), "Phae.long2.wav"))
>
> info_sound_files(path = tempdir())

Cheers